# removing and adding a class using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove a class and add a class to `div`s using jQuery but it doesn't seem to be working.

My html is like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>one</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>two</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to remove the class `col-sm-4` and instead add class `col-sm-6`

This is what I've done:

```
$("#foo").find(".col-sm-4").addClass(".col-sm-6").removeClass(".col-sm-4");
```

I've ensured that I am getting elements back by `find`

```
alert($("#foo").find(".col-sm-4").length); //2
```

Even though I'm not getting any errors, there is no change in my elements.

Comment: I wish jQuery would automatically strip out a leading `.` in the `addClass()` and similar methods. I myself make this error all the time.

Comment: Some basic debugging with the console, and reading the docs for the proper syntax for addClass and removeClass would've solved your problem.

Comment: While you were doing it wrong, [it does actually work](http://jsfiddle.net/3PE6Z/)

Comment: arghhh stupid me. I found the problem (adding .) after posting the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Novocaine88 It doesn't really work, does it? If it did, the text in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3PE6Z/1/) would be red.

Comment: @Novocaine88 not on my browser it doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/3PE6Z/2/

Comment: @agrm by work, what I meant is that it *does* add the class. Of course it added the incorrect class with the dot which was not needed, which was the problem in the first place. My comment was mainly in response to *there is no change in my elements.* which was in fact incorrect, the elements do change.

Comment: @Novocaine88 That's a good point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to include the `.` in the `col-sm-6` of the `.addClass` parameter; nor do you need to use `.find()`.

The following will work:

```
$("#foo div.col-sm-4").addClass("col-sm-6").removeClass("col-sm-4");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the methods addClass and removeClass, don't use the period to indicate the class name, so you should write

```
$("#foo").find(".col-sm-4").addClass("col-sm-6").removeClass("col-sm-4");
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) ".col-sm-6" is an example of a JQuery selector -**
Which, from the [JQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is: "Borrowing from CSS 1–3, and then adding its own, jQuery offers a powerful set of tools for matching a set of elements in a document."
The methods addClass and removeClass are functions that except a class name to add or subtract to the element's class attribute. You wrote it like a JQuery selector. You are using the concept of selectors correctly when you reference your object with the JQuery selector $("#foo div.col-sm-4").

**2) You say: "Even though I'm not getting any errors, there is no change in my elements." -** This is a great observation. You should know that much of JavaScript fails silently. Between 1 and 2 of this answer, I highly recommend the book [JavaScript: The Good Parts.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)